# Blank ipython notebook in jupyter

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, jupyter

First, the navigation keys (arrows, home, end, ...) stopped working in my ipython notebook (Ubuntu 14.04, both in firefox and chromium), then I followed the instructions in the section **Installing Jupyter (I already have Python)** in http://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html expecting than an upgrade would solve the problem, but now when I try to create a new Python2 notebook I just get a blank screen in my browser, the same happens when I try to load old notebooks. I don't see any errors in the command line. After that I installed anaconda (Python3) hoping that since it is self contained it would solve the issue, but it didn't. Any ideas of what could be causing this behavior?

EDIT:

The web console shows several errors and warnings. In the notebook home page it shows:

```
Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead main.min.js:1:0
accessing `Notebook` is deprecated. Use `require("notebook/js/notebook").Notebook` main.min.js:28:11
Error: Module name "notebook/js/notebook" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded require.js:165:17
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. main.min.js:5:12747
Reenabling autorefresh too close to last tree refresh, not refreshing immediately again. main.min.js:15253:13
Reenabling autorefresh too close to last tree refresh, not refreshing immediately again. main.min.js:15253:13
```

However, the notebook home works as expected. The new Python 3 notebook also shows JS warnings and errors:

```
Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead main.min.js:86:0
accessing `Notebook` is deprecated. Use `require("notebook/js/notebook").Notebook` main.min.js:21:11
accessing `RawCell` is deprecated. Use `require("notebook/js/textcell").RawCell` main.min.js:21:11
accessing `Cell` is deprecated. Use `require("notebook/js/cell").Cell` main.min.js:21:11
accessing `TextCell` is deprecated. Use `require("notebook/js/textcell").TextCell` main.min.js:21:11
accessing `MarkdownCell` is deprecated. Use `require("notebook/js/textcell").MarkdownCell` main.min.js:21:11
TypeError: IPython.HeadingCell is undefined custom.js:8:5
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. main.min.js:90:12747
Loaded extension: widgets/notebook/js/extension main.min.js:12030:17
TypeError: IPython.notebook is undefined
```

For the moment

```
/usr/bin/ipython3 notebook
```

works as in the beginning, i.e., I can do everything normally but arrow keys and home, end, pgUp, pgDown, insert, and delete, do not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be browser caching. Hit Ctrl-F5 a few times to force it to clear the cache and refresh.

Comment: @Thomas K Thanks for the suggestion but hitting Ctrl-F5 several times didn't solve the problem

Comment: Any errors in the browser's JS console?

Comment: @ThomasK There are several errors in the JS console (see edit). They seem to be the cause of my problems. Can you point out how to fix them?

Comment: I'm still suspecting browser caching. Can you run the notebook with `--port=8889` (or any number that's not the port it normally runs on). That should avoid what it has in cache.

Comment: @ThomasK Changing the port didn't work. I got the same errors in the JS console as before.

Comment: The only thing I can think to suggest is to try to uninstall all traces of the notebook from every way it's already installed, and install again from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that I had modified the custom.js file as instructed in http://undefd.kaihola.fi/2013/10/25/emacs-keybindings-for-ipython-notebook-and-firefox.html, This explains why the cursor keys were not working before upgrading to jupyter. Apparently, this modification was incompatible with the jupyter version of the notebook. Once I removed the corresponding file from the .jupyter directory the problem was solved.

Comment: did you manage to have emacs keybindings in a different way ?

Comment: There is an emacs ipython project, but I couldn't get it working. Here's the link to the project: 

https://tkf.github.io/emacs-ipython-notebook/